# Adding one element of an array to many elements of second array Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to add array in this manner

```
arr1=[1,2,3,4]
arr2=[4,5,6,7]
```

adding should be like

```
arr1[0]+arr2[0]
arr1[0]+arr2[1]
arr1[0]+arr2[2]
```

and so on similarly with other second and other elements of arr1

Comment: Go ahead. .....

Comment: I know the concatenation of two arrays but dnt know how to actually add the one element of an array with all elements of second array

Comment: What's your expected output @mashal?

Comment: out  should be like after adding the arr1[0]+arr2[0]=5
arr1[0]+arr2[1]=6
arr1[0]+arr2[2]=7

Comment: @mashal That are 3 results, is your expected result another array like `[5, 6, 7]`? And what about the remaining elements?

Comment: This should have included expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Try a combination of map over both arrays:

```
p [1,2,3,4].map { |e| [4,5,6,7].map { |f| f + e } }
# => [[5, 6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: hey sebastian do u have any idea how to do it in c?

Comment: @mashal stay focused, your question is about Ruby, not C.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1.product(arr2).map { |a,b| a + b }                                       
 #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Use `sum` maybe if you have Ruby > 2.4, otherwise you can use [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

```
arr1.product(arr2).map { |a| a.sum }
```

See [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-product) and [`Array#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-sum) for further information.